# How to fix a " 'Module' Object Not Callable Error " from a Keras Predictive Model

Tags: python, keras

Hi: When I try to execute the main Python code below I keep getting a TypeError that says that the "'Module' object is not callable".  My CSV dataset only has 1 column of float numbers.  I have also provided the helper function "LSTM.py" code. Where is the bug?

**Python Code:**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
    input_dim=1,
    output_dim=50,
    return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` for the line `"return_sequences=True))"`

```
**LSTM.py code:**

    import time
    import warnings
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import newaxis
    from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
    from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
    from keras.models import Sequential
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    def plot_results_multiple(predicted_data, true_data, prediction_len):
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(true_data, label='True Data')
        print ('yo')
    #Pad the list of predictions to shift it in the graph to it's correct start
    for i, data in enumerate(predicted_data):
        padding = [None for p in xrange(i * prediction_len)]
        plt.plot(padding + data, label='Prediction')
        plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    def load_data(filename, seq_len, normalise_window):
        f = open(filename, 'r').read()
        data = f.split('\n')

        sequence_length = seq_len + 1
        result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    if normalise_window:
        result = normalise_windows(result)

    result = np.array(result)

    row = round(0.9 * result.shape[0])
    train = result[:int(row), :]
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    x_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    x_test = result[int(row):, :-1]
    y_test = result[int(row):, -1]

    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))  

    return [x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test]

    def normalise_windows(window_data):
        normalised_data = []
         for window in window_data:
            normalised_window = [((float(p) / float(window[0])) - 1) for p in window]
            normalised_data.append(normalised_window)
    return normalised_data

     def build_model(layers):
        model = Sequential()

         model.add(LSTM(
             input_dim=layers[0],
             output_dim=layers[1],
             return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print ("Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model

    def predict_point_by_point(model, data):
    #Predict each timestep given the last sequence of true data, in effect only predicting 1 
    step ahead each time
         predicted = model.predict(data)
         predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))
         return predicted

     def predict_sequence_full(model, data, window_size):
         #Shift the window by 1 new prediction each time, re-run predictions on new window
         curr_frame = data[0]
         predicted = []
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        predicted.append(model.predict(curr_frame[newaxis,:,:])[0,0])
        curr_frame = curr_frame[1:]
        curr_frame = np.insert(curr_frame, [window_size-1], predicted[-1], axis=0)
    return predicted

     def predict_sequences_multiple(model, data, window_size, prediction_len):
         #Predict sequence of 50 steps before shifting prediction run forward by 50 steps
         prediction_seqs = []
        for i in xrange(len(data)/prediction_len):
             curr_frame = data[i*prediction_len]
             predicted = []
        for j in xrange(prediction_len):
            predicted.append(model.predict(curr_frame[newaxis,:,:])[0,0])
            curr_frame = curr_frame[1:]
            curr_frame = np.insert(curr_frame, [window_size-1], predicted[-1], axis=0)
        prediction_seqs.append(predicted)
    return prediction_seqs
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name of one of your scripts is the same as a Keras class, LSTM.py and the LSTM class in this case. Do **not** do that, as it creates conflicts.

You should rename your script to not have a conflicting name.

Comment: Now I have a new problem. In the last function "predict_sequences_multiple", there are 2 arrows: 1 arrow pointing to line 2 "predictions = neuron.predict_sequences_multiple(model, X_test, 50, 50)" and another arrow pointing to line 101 "for i in range(len(data)/prediction_len):" It is a Type Error stating,"'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".  Before this error, Python said that "xrange" is just "range" in Python 3.  When I changed to "range", then the TypeError message above came out. Hope you can help.

Comment: @ubk046 Division produces floats, if you want integer division you should use // or cast to integer

Comment: After using //, my output is not the same as if I had used / in line 101 "for i in range(len(data)/prediction_len):" .  Can you tell me which line of code is producing the float number which is making this For-Loop not able to run?

Comment: @ubk046 I don't understand what you mean by output not the same.I can only debug what I see.

Comment: Is there way to send you the 2 graphs by email or something to show you that one is the correct graph and the other is the one using "//"?

Comment: @ubk046 No, you can always make new questions, as this is not really a clarification of the answer but a new question